# Sort multidimensional JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array

I have following array from facebook graph API.
I want to sort it by comment_count, like_count, time in javascript.

```
[
  {
   "status_id": "1",
   "message": "message1",
   "comment_info": {
     "comment_count": "1"
    },
    "like_info": {
    "like_count": "0"
   },
  "time": "1380046653"
  },
 {
  "status_id": "2",
  "message": "message2",
  "comment_info": {
   "comment_count": "2"
  },
  "like_info": {
   "like_count": "5"
  },
  "time": "1368109884"
 }
```

]
I wrote function like below,

```
function sortResults(prop, asc) {
 statusString = statusString.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (asc) return (a[prop] > b[prop]) ? 1 : ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
    else return (b[prop] > a[prop]) ? 1 : ((b[prop] < a[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
 });
 console.log(statusString);
}
```

And on button click

```
sortResults(['comment_info']['comment_count'], true);
```

But it sorts weiredly.

Comment: Do you understand what `['comment_info']['comment_count']` is doing? What is your expectation for that code?

Comment: And your requirements are unclear. Do you want to sort by *one* of those properties? Or do you want to sub-sort by those properties when equality is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function didnt' take in consideration multi dimensional sort which needs to access deep property of nested arrays.
Here is a working example [JSFIDLE link (click here)](http://jsfiddle.net/JjV4X/)

```
var jSon = [{"status_id":"1","message":"message1","comment_info":{"comment_count":"1"},"like_info":{"like_count":"0"},"time":"1380046653"},{"status_id":"2","message":"message2","comment_info":{"comment_count":"2"},"like_info":{"like_count":"5"},"time":"1368109884"}];


// Function that sorts arr Array
// by prop (handling custom Fb cases)
// in dir direction (asc/desc)
function sortJson(arr, prop, dir) {
    return arr.sort(function(a,b) {
        var propA,propB;
        if (prop == "comment_count") {
            propA = a['comment_info']['comment_count'];
            propB = b['comment_info']['comment_count'];
        } else if (prop == "like_count") {
            propA = a['like_info']['like_count'];
            propB = b['like_info']['like_count'];
        } else {
            propA = a[prop];
            propB = b[prop];
        }

        if (dir=='asc') {
            return propA - propB;
        } else {
            return propB - propA;
        }
    });
}

console.log( sortJson(jSon, 'time', 'asc') );
console.log( sortJson(jSon, 'comment_count', 'asc') );
console.log( sortJson(jSon, 'like_count', 'desc').toString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need sort function from native [].

[].sort(compareFunction)
example from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) :

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion)
     return -1;
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion)
     return 1;
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say your order in the sort is as you have mentioned them:

```
var arr = [{"status_id":"1","message":"message1","comment_info":{"comment_count":"1"},"like_info":{"like_count":"0"},"time":"1380046653"},{"status_id":"2","message":"message2","comment_info":{"comment_count":"2"},"like_info":{"like_count":"5"},"time":"1368109884"}];
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    var countA = parseInt(a["comment_info"]["comment_count"]);
    var countB = parseInt(b["comment_info"]["comment_count"]);

    var likeCountA = parseInt(a["like_info"]["like_count"]);
    var likeCountB = parseInt(b["like_info"]["like_count"]);

    var timeA = a["time"];
    var timeB = b["time"];

    return ((countA - countB) || (likeCountA - likeCountB) || (timeA - timeB));
});
```